# How to create a csv file to record pwm data on raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a PWM signal with using a button on Raspberry PI Model 4 then tried to record the values of pwm over the time, for this reason I imported the datetime to PI to save the time info to csv file also then added a pull-up button when I run the code it raises this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pwm.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 44 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
```

and the code is

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pandas as pd
import datetime

LED = 17
Button = 27
duty = 0

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

p = GPIO.PWM(LED, 100)

shutter_csv = pd.DataFrame()

current_date_time = datetime.now()

try:
    while 1:
        ButtonState = GPIO.input(Button)

        if ButtonState == False:
            p.start(duty)
            for change_duty in range(0,101,5):
                p.ChangeDutyCycle(change_duty)
                time.sleep(0.2)
               
            for change_duty in range(100, -1, -5):
                p.ChangeDutyCycle(change_duty)
                time.sleep(0.2)
               
        shutter_csv.append(current_date_time)
        shutter_csv.append(p,ignore_index = True)
       
        p.stop()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Program stopped via keyboard interrupt")
    p.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup()
   
finally:
    shutter_csv.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: What versions of Pandas and NumPy do you have installed on your RPI?

Comment: i just installed by using pip3 install

Comment: Can you run this: `python3 -c 'import pandas; import numpy; print(pandas.__version__, numpy.__version__)'`

Comment: if for some reason there are issues installing pandas on your RPi, consider using the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html): it's not as feature rich as pandas but for a simple script like this should do the trick. Good luck!